# Unable to create histogram from slice due to datetime datatype error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am looking to remove the upper outliers of some columns in a DataFrame (specifically in the 'vehicle_age' and 'odometer' columns in order to then build a histogram.

I have been able to successfully build the initial histograms like so:

```
crankshaft_ads['odometer'].plot(kind='hist', bins=25, range= (0, 1000000))
```

And I would like to build histograms without the upper outliers, as a comparison. Here is what I tried so far:

```
q1_age = crankshaft_ads['vehicle_age'].quantile(0.25)
q1_odometer = crankshaft_ads['odometer'].quantile(0.25)

q3_age = crankshaft_ads['vehicle_age'].quantile(0.75)
q3_odometer = crankshaft_ads['odometer'].quantile(0.75)

iqr_age = q3_age - q1_age
iqr_odometer = q3_odometer - q1_odometer

upper_limit_age = q3_age + (1.5 * iqr_age)
upper_limit_odometer = q3_odometer + (1.5 * iqr_odometer)

crankshaft_ads['upper_limit_age'] = upper_limit_age
crankshaft_ads['upper_limit_odometer'] = upper_limit_odometer

(crankshaft_ads
    .query('vehicle_age < upper_limit_age')
    .plot(kind='hist', bins=10)
)

(crankshaft_ads
    .query('odometer < upper_limit_odometer')
    .plot(kind='hist', bins=25)
)
```

I would need help with the .query() elements. I get the following error (it happens when running the .plot line it seems):
**ValueError: view limit minimum -49500.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units**

There is one column in the DataFrame that has datetime datatype, but **what I'm trying to do is build a histogram for the 2 columns mentioned above, with the upper outliers filtered out**. Is this the wrong approach?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not selected the columns you want to plot in your plotting functions. The queries you have written select a subset of the whole dataframe, not only the column mentioned in each query. So both plotting functions are attempting to plot a histogram for each column in a single figure, including the datetime column.

Here are three ways you could solve this problem, taking your first plotting function as an example:

```
# Solution 1: apply query to whole dataframe then select column in plotting function
crankshaft_ads.query('vehicle_age < @upper_limit_age').plot.hist(y='vehicle_age', bins=10)
```

```
# Solution 2: first select column then select values to plot in histogram
crankshaft_ads['vehicle_age'][crankshaft_ads['vehicle_age'] < upper_limit_age].plot.hist(bins=10)
```

```
# Solution 3: first select all dataframe rows meeting condition then select column in plotting function
crankshaft_ads[crankshaft_ads['vehicle_age'] < upper_limit_age].plot.hist(y='vehicle_age', bins=10)
```